# Staircase pattern with numbers (Angular)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make use of the staircase pattern but using numbers. In which I am using angular but I am not finding the solution. This is what I would be trying to achieve:

[image]

I leave the code that I have done so far:

**main.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'main-component',
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './main.component.html'
})
export class MainComponent {
    @Input()
    elements: number = 1;
    max = 100;
    x = new Array();

    ngOnInit() {
       this.updateValue();
    }

    updateValue() {
       this.x = new Array();
       for (let i = 1; i <= this.elements; i++) {
          this.x.push(i);
       }
    }
}
```

**main.html**

```
<p>Number input:</p>
<input
  type="number"
  min="1"
  max="100"
  (change)="updateValue()"
  [(ngModel)]="elements"
/>
<div>
<p>Staircase: </p>
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of x">
       <td *ngFor="let td of x"> {{row}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

and this is what I have achieved so far, just make a matrix in which the numbers are repeated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you need.

Typescript

```
elements: number = 32;
max = 100;
x: any[] = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateValue();
}
updateValue() {
    this.x = [];
    let idx = 1;
    let last = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.elements; i++) {
        const inner: number[] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < idx; j++) {
            if (last > this.elements) break;
            inner.push(last);
            last++;
        }
        this.x.push(inner);
        idx++;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<p>Number input:</p>
<input
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="100"
    (change)="updateValue()"
    [(ngModel)]="elements"
/>
<div>
<p>Staircase: </p>
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of x">
      <td *ngFor="let td of row"
        style="padding: 10px; background-color: gray; text-align: center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bolder;">
        {{td}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it helps you to keep going:

[image]

```
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of x; index as i">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of x; index as j">
        <td *ngIf="i >= j">{{ item }}</td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution could be to write function to map numbers to an array:

```js
// Will generate array in a form [[startingNumber], [startingNumber, startingNumber + 1], etc...]
  generateNumber = (startingNumber, numberOfElements) => {

    const lastNumber = startingNumber + numberOfElements - 1, resultArray = [];

    let currentGap = 1;

    while (true) {

      const subArray = [];

      for (let j = startingNumber; startingNumber < (j + currentGap) && startingNumber <= lastNumber; startingNumber++) {
        subArray.push(startingNumber);
      }

      resultArray.push(subArray);

      if (startingNumber > lastNumber) return resultArray;

      currentGap++;

    }

  }
  
  // Generated array
  console.log(generateNumber(1, 7));
```

Generate array using the function above. Resulting array will be something like [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8]]. You can then in Angular write two nested loops and render content of it.

```html
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of resultArray">
        <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{ item }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```